# Trying to define an asset compiler in Compoundjs and getting undefined method error

Tags: javascript, node.js, compoundjs

I'm trying to define an asset compiler [according to the documentation](http://compoundjs.com/docs/#asset-compiler-adding-your-own-compiler)http://compoundjs.com/docs/#asset-compiler-adding-your-own-compiler, however, I keep getting an error:

```
app.use(compound.assetsCompiler.add('scss', {
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined
```

My entire `environment.js` file looks like:

```
module.exports = function (compound) {

    var express = require('express');
    var app = compound.app;

    app.configure(function (){
      app.use(compound.assetsCompiler.add('scss', {
        render: function (str, options, fn) {
          try {
            fn(null, @scss.render(str));
          } catch (err) {
            fn(err);
          }   
        },  
        scss: require('node-sass'),
        sourceExtension: 'scss',
        destExtension: 'css'
      }).init());

      app.use(express.static(app.root + '/public', { maxAge: 86400000 }));
      app.set('jsDirectory', '/javascripts/');
      app.set('cssDirectory', '/stylesheets/');
      app.set('cssEngine', 'scss');
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
      app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret'}));
      app.use(express.methodOverride());
      app.use(app.router);
    }); 

};
```

I tried a `console.log(compound.assetsCompiler);` just before the `app.use(compount.assetsCompiler...` statement and sure enough I get `undefined`. The documentation also says to use `compound.assetCompiler.add(...);` (singular asset) which I assume is a typo but since it got that typo wrong multiple times I tried it as well but had the same problem. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Or at least the workaround. Although it seems that the autoloader require the `AssetsCompiler` it doesn't initialize it, the solution is to require the object and manually initialize it in the `environment.js`

```
module.exports = function (compound) {
  'use strict';
  var express = require('express');
  var app = compound.app;
  // require the assetsCompiler
  var compiler = require('co-assets-compiler');

  app.configure(function () {
    // calling the init function will add the assetsCompiler object
    // to the compound object and everything else should now work
    // as expected
    compiler.init(compound);
    app.use(compound.assetsCompiler.add('scss', {
     render: function (str, options, fn) {
         @scss.render(str, ƒ (err, css) {
          fn(err,css);         
        },{                    
          includePaths: [app.root + '/app/assets/stylesheets/'] 
      });
    },
      scss: require('node-sass'),
      sourceExtension: 'scss', 
      destExtension: 'css'     
    }).init());  

    app.use(express.static(app.root + '/public', { maxAge: 86400000 }));
    app.set('jsDirectory', '/javascripts/');
    app.set('cssDirectory', '/stylesheets/');
    app.set('cssEngine', 'scss');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret'}));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
  });
};
```